# CoreGraphics taking a while to show on a large view - can i get it to repeat pixels?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-graphics

This is my coregraphics code:

```
void drawTopPaperBackground(CGContextRef context, CGRect rect) {

    CGRect paper3 = CGRectMake(10, 14, 300, rect.size.height - 14);
    CGRect paper2 = CGRectMake(13, 12, 294, rect.size.height - 12);
    CGRect paper1 = CGRectMake(16, 10, 288, rect.size.height - 10);

    //Shadow
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(0,0), 10, [[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.5]CGColor]);
    CGPathRef path = createRoundedRectForRect(paper3, 0);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextAddPath(context, path);
    CGContextFillPath(context);

    //Layers of paper
    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    drawPaper(context, paper3);
    drawPaper(context, paper2);
    drawPaper(context, paper1);

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

}

void drawPaper(CGContextRef context, CGRect rect) {
    //Shadow
    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(0,0), 1, [[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.5]CGColor]);

    CGPathRef path = createRoundedRectForRect(rect, 0);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextAddPath(context, path);
    CGContextFillPath(context);

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    //Gradient

    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    CGColorRef startColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.92 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
    CGColorRef endColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.94 alpha:1.0].CGColor;

    CGRect firstHalf = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x,
                                  rect.origin.y, rect.size.width / 2, rect.size.height);
    CGRect secondHalf = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x + (rect.size.width / 2),
                                  rect.origin.y, rect.size.width / 2, rect.size.height);

    drawVerticalGradient(context, firstHalf, startColor, endColor);
    drawVerticalGradient(context, secondHalf, endColor, startColor);

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    CGRect redRect = rectForRectWithInset(rect, -1);
    CGMutablePathRef redPath = createRoundedRectForRect(redRect, 0);


    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]);

    CGContextAddPath(context, path);
    CGContextClip(context);

    CGContextAddPath(context, redPath);
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(0, 0), 15.0, [[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.1] CGColor]);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

}
```

The view is a UIScrollView, which contains a textview. Every time the user types something and goes onto a new line, I call `[self setNeedsDisplay];` and it redraws the code. But when the view starts to get long - around 1000 height, it has very noticeable lag. How can i make this code more efficient? Can i take a line of pixels and make it just repeat that, or stretch it, all the way down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw your repeating background once, into an offscreen context, pull out the image from it, then create a UIColor with the pattern image and set that as your background colour. The image will then be tiled for you.

You start an image context with `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions()`. The options include the size of your expected image - I assume this is the width of your scrollview and x pixels high, the opacity, and scale. Send 0 for the scale for automatic retina support.

You can then act as if you were within a drawRect method - so your functions above can be called as normal.

Then, extract the image:

```
UIImage *background = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

End the image context:

```
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Then create the colour:

```
UIColor *backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:background];
```

And set that as the background for your scrollview. Typed on a phone, so apologies for ... everything.

Comment: How do i cache something? And how do i code the third option?

Comment: I think the third option is best so I'll update the answer with some guidelines on that one rather than having a bunch of options.